# Is every minimal graph smooth?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature, minimal-surfaces

The following result was taken from the book of Gilbarg-Trudinger:

[image: Corollary]

In particular, if the graph is minimal, then $u$ is smooth.

**Now comes my question:** does the same conclusion hold for graphs over domains in smooth Riemannian manifolds? To be more precise: suppose that $\Omega \subset M$ is a smooth bounded domain in a smooth Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, and let $u \in C^2(\Omega)$ be a function whose graph

$$\Gamma(u) := \{(x, u(x)) \in \Omega \times \mathbb{R} : x \in \Omega \}$$

is minimal in the product metric of $\Omega \times \mathbb{R}$. Does it follow that $u$ is smooth?

Comment: It does - you can just use the usual regularity theory for quasilinear operators and bootstrapping, no?

Comment: I am far from being an expert in regularity theory..

Comment: Yes, the same result will hold on a Riemannian manifold and you can probably adapt the arguments from elsewhere in the book to prove that result. I am by no mean an expert in the field of minimal surfaces but, in general, everything (regarding regularity) that is true for bounded domains with smooth boundary will also be true for bounded domains on a manifold. This follows by the usual method of "freezing the coefficients".